# How to change background of grid depending on whether a variable is true or false

Tags: extjs4

If I have a grid, how can I change it's background image depending on whether a certain variable is true or false?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to change all cells background or an individual cell background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant a background image for the entire grid then you can use viewConfig of the grid panel to set a custom CSS property with the background image

```
viewConfig:{
   cls : myVar?'myCustomClass':''
}
```

CSS:

```
.myCustomClass {
    background:url("http://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff") repeat 0 0;
}
```

here is a full example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dbrin/bQvyg/10/

Must say it doesn't look great.

EDIT: "HardWorker" asked how to change it programatically after the component is rendered. So here is how:

```
grid.view.removeCls('myCustomClass')       
grid.view.addCls("myOtherCustomClass")
```

Comment: Hi this is what I want but you have done it so it has to be specified in the component definition e.g. the initComponent. I want it so the background can be changed after the grid panel has been created. So the grid is created, and later on a handler checks if a certain variable has been set true or false and sets the background accordingly.

Comment: grid.view.removeCls('myCustomClass')       grid.view.addCls("myOtherCustomClass")